# How to escape characters in python impyla query for Cloudera Impala running on Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, cloudera, impala, impyla

I am trying to escape characters in python impyla query for Cloudera Impala on Hadoop but nothing seems to work.. The template syntax doesn't escape (Unusual for a database API..)

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * from table where col1 = %s', tuple(["John's unescaped string"]))
```

produces an error.

Even

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * from table where col1 = %s', tuple([json.dumps("John's unescaped string")]))
```

doesn't work, does anyone have any idea how to provide a solution for this? Is there a better way or a more fully featured Impala library for Python?

Comment: Can you edit this to show the error that is produced?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameterized query with `?` placeholders

`cursor.execute('INSERT INTO table VALUES (?, ?);', (var1, var2))`

However impyla does still have other issues with quote-escaping and unicode that I haven't fully figured out yet.